# Different execution count for queries in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-execution-plan

I've executed a stored procedure with the following T-SQL code:

```
exec myStoredProcedure
go 10
```

After the execution of the procedure I reviewed the information in `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` and observed that for some queries in the stored procedure, the value in `Execution Count` is different.

[image]

Apparently, some execution plans have been ran only a number of times, 7 out of 10, for some queries in the stored procedure.

The data in the above screenshot is being returned with the following query:

```
select ...
    qs.execution_count [Execution Count]
from sys.dm_exec_query_stats as qs
    cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text (qs.sql_handle) as st
    cross apply sys.dm_exec_text_query_plan (qs.plan_handle, qs.statement_start_offset, qs.statement_end_offset) as qp
where st.objectid = object_id('myStoredProcedure')
```

And as you can see, there is no other execution plan stored for this procedure where the execution count is `3`, thinking that the Optimizer decided to run a query with another plan.

Truth is some of the queries that have an execution count of `7` are inserts into different temporary tables, with `SELECT INTO #temptable`, but not all of them.

So, **my question is** why do some queries have a plan which has been executed a smaller number of times than others and how did those queries execute and with what plan?

*I'd like to mention that there is no logic in the stored procedure that would generate different execution flows so that some queries do not get executed. (no **IFs**)*

***Also***, no statistics update or DML queries have been ran in the meantime so that row-count or index changes have occurred.

Is my query which goes over the `DMV` not correct and does not pick up these "rogue" plans? Or has the data been cached in memory / tempdb for the temporary tables and read from there on subsequent executions?

**Update:**

*Added a screenshot containing the column with `plan_generation_num` requested by `@MartinBrown`*

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Execution_Count field is defined as:

"Number of times that the plan has been executed since it was last compiled."

That would suggest that on on the fourth run some of the plans were re-compiled. I would suspect this happened due to the original plans falling out of the cache.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741.aspx

Comment: Well, no `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` is specified either on procedure level or on statement level. Still, what new execution plans have been used for those queries and where are those new "rogue" plans? Shouldn't my DMV query pick them up? (I'm assuming that even if the old plans got dropped, some new plans were used to execute the queries) - if my knowledge is correct.

Comment: There are lots of factors that can cause a recompile: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9054308/20553. The OLD plans (pre recompile) have been lost from cache I would think. The creation times on your plans look like they are the new plans.

Comment: What are the plan_generation_num values?

Comment: I added the screenshot with the `plan_generation_num`. I'm a bit confused as to what that means. Instance of a plan after a recompile? Are there more instances of a plan after a recompile? Wouldn't a different instance mean a different plan?

Comment: Does that number mean that after a recompile the optimizer came up with the same plan (which it used) and thus incremented the `plan_generation_num` value? But .. did not increment the `execution_count` value? (*this sounds a bit crazy*), I' still confused..

Comment: Plan caching is a complex thing and stretches my knowledge. However I know that since the 2005 version SQL Server has been able to recompile a small part of a Query plan. Also there are two levels of caching, both a plan cache and an execution context cache. How all that relates to the plan_generation and execution_count fields I'm not sure. There may be more details in this white paper https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn148262.aspx

Comment: Thank you @MartinBrown! I'll be sure to check it out, this is all fairly new to me as well.