# List of items that trigger recompiling an SP without any "RECOMPILE" option

Tags: sql-server, query-performance

Using SQL Server 2014:

What are the items that trigger recompiling an SP without any "RECOMPILE" option?

I am concern that the SP query plan stays the same forever if we don't restart the SQL server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What factors can cause Stored Procedure Recompilation on SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054100/what-factors-can-cause-stored-procedure-recompilation-on-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

There's quite many things that can trigger recompilation, I'd say most common ones are most likely statistics changing, restart, plan cache being full or changes to schema (including temp. tables)

You can read more from for example [here](http://www.sqlshack.com/frequent-query-recompilations-sql-query-performance-killer-detection/), [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/02/18/sql-server-plan-recompilation-and-reduce-recompilation-performance-tuning/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054100/what-factors-can-cause-stored-procedure-recompilation-on-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Usually these kinds of issues are indicative of some design issues, but that aside, if you want to guarantee the plan you are using, take a look at the "USE PLAN" query hint that would persist even through a server restart.  Trying to avoid recompiles is nearly impossible without some type of query hint.