# MS SQL Server: prevent execution plans going out-of-date

Tags: sql-server, performance, statistics, sql-server-2016, sql-execution-plan

My application has some queries (complex ones with fulltext-search). The queries usually run fast and often (let's say 30x/h). But periodically (lets say every two or three weeks) it looks like Sql Server drops the execution plan and the queries are extremely slow.

After running "EXEC sp_updatestats" the queries are fast again.

Anyone has an idea of what I can do to find the reason for this problem?

Installed SQL Server version is 13.0.4224.16, running on Windows Server 2016. The application doesn't make use of stored procedures.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What factors can cause Stored Procedure Recompilation on SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054100/what-factors-can-cause-stored-procedure-recompilation-on-sql-server)

Comment: [Understanding SQL Server Recompilations](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5308/understanding-sql-server-recompilations/)

Comment: thanks, but i don't use stored procedures in this application and this answer is very much related to them.